# Simple SQL tutorial configuration difficulty

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello Im trying to load the sample database like in this tutorial:

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/

It says "First, launch the psql tool.", does it mean the pgadmin programm, or the sql shell(psql)?

Where can I succesfully put in the following commands in pgadmin? I dont believe it belongs to the SQL query field, plz help me.

Comment: Launch whatever works for you. Pgadmin tool should be easier to work with if you're new to PG-SQL.

Comment: @CraigRinger make this an answer, I've deleted mine :)

Answer (score 1):

The does indeed mean the command-line tool `psql`, but you could just as easily create the database from within PgAdmin-III's GUI. Just right click on "Databases" and then "New Database". Or use PgAdmin-III's SQL executor window to run the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

Personally I recommend getting familiar with `psql`. Some things, like `\` commands, will *only* work in `psql`. People keep on trying to run `\copy`, `\d`, etc in PgAdmin-III and getting confused when it doesn't work. `psql` is also - in my opinion - a lot more productive once you're used to working with it. Even if you regularly use PgAdmin-III you'll want to know how to use `psql` for some things like loading an SQL-format dump, so you might as well get onto it sooner rather than later.

(BTW, that site is ... weird. I've never seen it before, it has masked data in whois, there's no contact info or information about who wrote it, no apparent commercial links. Interesting.)

Consider reading the official [postgresql tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html); it tries to *explain* more, rather than just giving step-by-step instructions. It also requires a bit more understanding though, as it's written more for Linux/unix users and contains install instructions that won't apply to you on Windows.

Comment: thank you for the fast answers..., but I still have problems executing the given commands from http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/ . Am I puttin in a wrong username? Take a look at this screenshot: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/fmij9dw3/noresult.png

Comment: @user2671998 Um... So many things wrong with that. `pg_restore` is a separate command run in the shell, *not* a `psql` command. You didn't  finish logging in to the database, you just started typing the shell command before finishing all the prompts, so it would never work anyway. Perhaps you're better off starting here?: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html

Comment: @user2671998 The immediate problem is that when `psql` asks you "what server do you want to connect to" with the `Server: ` prompt, you put in `CREATE DATABASE ...`. Understandably that doesn't work.